# MS Access to SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, ms-access

I am trying to move my rapidly growing MS Access 2016 database to a SQL Server back end and build an asp.net front end. I am trying to migrate data from the Access database to an instance of SQL server 2014 but this is not going so well. I tried to migrate it using the MS Migration Assistant but this is not supported for versions after 2010. Does anyone know an easy way to convert Access tables to SQL Server?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: No, it was the built-in "SQL Server Upsizing Wizard" that was dropped after Access 2010. The [SQL Server Migration Assistant for Access](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh313039(v=sql.110).aspx) is the current tool.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only migration assistant that was depreciated was the one built into Access. So you are correct that after Access 2010, the migration system is removed.

However, there is a SQL Migration Assistant for Access that can be used here:

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=54255

The above SSMA for Access is better than the old migration assent and is designed for upgrading Access to SQL server.

NOTE CAREFULLY that the shortcut on the desktop is for office x64 which FEW have, so make sure you launch the x32 bit version of SSMA – you find the shortcut to x32 in the programs folder (or just type I SSMA in windows 10 and select the x32 version.

AGAIN:
Make sure you follow above to launch the x32 version else it will not work.

Comment: Awesome. This product just came out at the end of the year so I didn't even know about it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Create your database in SQLServer

In Management studio, Right click on your database. Go to

Tasks
Import data

This should bring up the SQL Server Import and Export Wizard

In Data source, choose Microsoft Access. I have 3 choices in my test server. I'm not sure what one to use, so it might pay to play around.

Follow the Wizard, which should get you to were you want to be

Answer (score 0):

To automate migration from Microsoft Access database(s) to SQL Server

SQL Server Migration Assistant (SSMA) is a free supported tool

A video tutorial and all procedure I posted on the blog:

https://www.imran.xyz/convert-microsoft-access-database-to-sql-server-database/

You can download it from Microsoft 
https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=54255